Transaction revert in uniswap universal router
I want to sell token using universal router on Base network but transaction is getting reverted. Can anyone solve this?
CODE
require('dotenv').config();
const Web3 = require('web3');
const routerABI = require('./abis/routerABI.json');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.base.org'));
const senderAddress = process.env.SENDER_ADDRESS;
const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const routerAddress = '0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad'; // Router contract address
const wethAddress = '0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006'; // WETH contract address
const everyAddress = '0x717d31A60a9e811469673429c9F8Ea24358990f1'; // EVERY contract address

const routerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(routerABI, routerAddress);

const approveAndSwap = async () => {
  try {
    const wethContract = new web3.eth.Contract([
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "_spender",
            "type": "address"
          },
          {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
          }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      }
    ], wethAddress);

    const approveTx = wethContract.methods.approve(routerAddress, web3.utils.toWei('0.00001', 'ether'));
    const encodedTx = approveTx.encodeABI();
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();

    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress);
    const txObject = {
      nonce: nonce,
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(210000),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
      to: wethAddress,
      data: encodedTx
    };

    const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txObject, privateKey);
    const txReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
    console.log('WETH approved successfully:', txReceipt.transactionHash);

    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 300; // 5 minutes from now
    const executeTx = routerContract.methods.execute('0x000604', [], deadline);
    const executeData = executeTx.encodeABI();

    const executeTxObject = {
      nonce: nonce + 1,
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(4000000),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
      to: routerAddress,
      data: executeData,
      value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.00001', 'ether'))
    };

    const signedExecuteTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(executeTxObject, privateKey);
    const executeTxReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedExecuteTx.rawTransaction);
    console.log('Swap executed successfully:', executeTxReceipt.transactionHash);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
  }
};

approveAndSwap();

ERROR
WETH approved successfully: 0x8f4b3aeec1416a35848457797a5ab3a63fa6577f59b4645726a963aaf241239e
Error occurred: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x131e3f86545a6c3197110b9539fedaa69ec983d372b95381b17bf2c6448e5f14",
  "blockNumber": 13634033,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 9880218,
  "effectiveGasPrice": 223841404,
  "from": "0xba1347eab403faed265e906634a6d5962d1e68dd",
  "gasUsed": 27711,
  "l1Fee": "0xe1e1507eb",
  "l1GasPrice": "0x4ae025823",
  "l1GasUsed": "0xab4",
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
  "transactionHash": "0x8a006bbfe651989d0f31dfa5285d9c83ca6f417a94d40f8af3ee58d6acf4818f",
  "transactionIndex": 51,
  "type": "0x0"
}
    at Object.TransactionError (d:\every swap\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:90:21)
    at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (d:\every swap\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:101:21)
    at d:\every swap\node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:396:57
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  receipt: {
    blockHash: '0x131e3f86545a6c3197110b9539fedaa69ec983d372b95381b17bf2c6448e5f14',
    blockNumber: 13634033,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 9880218,
    effectiveGasPrice: 223841404,
    from: '0xba1347eab403faed265e906634a6d5962d1e68dd',
    gasUsed: 27711,
    l1Fee: '0xe1e1507eb',
    l1GasPrice: '0x4ae025823',
    l1GasUsed: '0xab4',
    logs: [],
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: false,
    to: '0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad',
    transactionHash: '0x8a006bbfe651989d0f31dfa5285d9c83ca6f417a94d40f8af3ee58d6acf4818f',
    transactionIndex: 51,
    type: '0x0'
  }
} 


You missed all the inputs in the execute data. https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/universal-router/technical-reference#command-inputs
